# Installing Pow.cx with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, pow.cx

I'm trying to build a chef script to get a dev box up and running and one of those steps will be to install [pow.cx](http://pow.cx/).

I first tried through the `curl` method as listed in their docs, but that requires it to be run as a local user, then you're prompted for a sudo password which i obv can't do with chef.

So I thought I'd try the `homebrew` recipe and run `pow --install-system` as root and `pow --install-local` as the `current_user`.

For some reason however the chef installation hangs on the `install-local` portion of the installation. I have no idea why because it works when I do it from the command line and creates the plist file just fine... but for whatever reason when running with chef, it just hangs.

I don't know much about chef OR pow but I'm wondering what might be causing this hang? On the command line running it doesn't prompt for input or anything. I'm pretty sure it's just building a plist file to then be launched with launchctl.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can avoid this timeout?

Comment: Is it waiting for input?